# LIKE Clause Error: Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL

Tags: apex, soql

i'm running a dynamic search, i want to add "where field like" conditions like this

```
 filter =  ' Name LIKE :(%'+ RowFilter.get('Name') + '%) AND'+
            'Account.Name LIKE :(%' + RowFilter.get('Account.Name') + '%)'

 affairePotentilleList = Database.query(query + 'Where ' + filter);
```

PS: RowFilter is map

```
   Map<string,string> RowFilter
```

I get this error:

> Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually not using bind capability below:

```
' Name LIKE :(%'+ RowFilter.get('Name') + '%) AND'
```

Bind `:` is used directly in string or soql but here you are concatenating the value to string.

and since you need to get from map, you cannot use bind `:`

try this:

```
filter =  ' Name LIKE \'%'+ RowFilter.get('Name') + '%\' AND'+
        ' Account.Name LIKE \'%' + RowFilter.get('Account.Name') + '%\'';

    affairePotentilleList = Database.query(query + 'Where ' + filter);
```

corrected the spacing also.

Comment: it works ! but I have 8 values in my map, is there not a better way for the code to be readable and clean,

Comment: changed answer based on your need. Pls mark as accepted if it solved.

Answer (score 0):

In dynamic SOQL you can bind variables but nothing more complex. So you could, for example have:

```
String nameFilter = '%' + RowFilter.get('Name') + '%';
String acctNameFilter = '%' + RowFilter.get('Account.Name') + '%';
String filter =  ' Name LIKE :nameFilter AND Account.Name LIKE :acctNameFilter';
```